# wsimport generates faulty code

Tags: java, wsimport

I use wsimport to generate my java stub files. For this, I use an ant build file in Eclipse:

```
<taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="../lib">
            <include name="jaxws-tools.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="generate">
    <wsimport wsdl="../wsdl/Knowledgebase.wsdl"
              destdir="../bin"
              sourcedestdir="../gen"
              keep="true"
              xendorsed="true">
    </wsimport>
</target>
```

The task runs without any errors. It creates different java-files, also Knowledgebase.java and KnowledgebasePort.java. In der Knowledgebase.java, there are these constructors:

```
public Knowledgebase(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), KNOWLEDGEBASE_QNAME, features);
}
```

For them I get an error "The constructor Service(...) is undefined". I imported the current jax-ws jar files. Is my generation process broken, do I use the wrong jars or where is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Service object is provided by the Java EE SDK.  It added a new constructor between Java EE 5 and Java EE 6.  It would seem the wsimport you're using is from a Java EE 6 JDK and the compiler is using a Java EE 5 SDK?

Comment: I feared that is something about this version conflicts :-( In my project settings I have set Java Compiler > Compiler Compliance Level at 1.6. Where else could be the mismatch?

Comment: So is this in Eclipse?  It also appears you're using Ant.  In order to use wsimport you need to define it with a taskdef.  Can you post the taskdef?  What are you using for the classpath?

Comment: To make the JDK use a different version you need to add the new api jars to that JDK itself, You add jars to the endorsed directory. That is <JAVA_HOME>/jre/lib/endorsed. I have jaxb-api and jaxws-api in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

If we using for example java 1.6.0_27 and Metro 2.2 we need to ENDORSE the webservices-api.jar.

1. We have to put this jar into folder `java-install-dir`\jre\lib\endorsed\
2. In case of using Eclipse, we have to ensure that we are using the correct JRE from the directory `java-install-dir`. This is done in Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs->Add.

Now the error  "The constructor Service(...) is undefined" should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You can set xendorsed="true" and xnocompile="false" and let ant compile your generated java files and it worked for me

```
<taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${ext.myproject.path}/lib">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${platformhome}/resources/ant/lib">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>    
</taskdef>

<macrodef name="myproject_before_compile_core">
        <sequential>
            <mkdir dir="${ext.myproject.path}/gensrc"/>
            <mkdir dir="${ext.myproject.path}/classes"/>
            <echo message="Generating WS stubs for Simulate BOM Service"/>
            <wsimport wsdl="${ext.myproject.path}/resources/wsdl/service.wsdl" package="com.xx.energy.yy.xyz.ws.stubs.service" xnocompile="false" destdir="${ext.myproject.path}/classes" sourcedestdir="${ext.myproject.path}/gensrc" keep="true" wsdlLocation="${ext.myproject.path}/resources/wsdl" xendorsed="true">
                <produces dir="${ext.myproject.path}/gensrc/com/xx/energy/yy/xyz/ws/stubs/service">
                    <include name="*.java"/>
                </produces>
                <depends file="${ext.myproject.path}/resources/wsdl/service.wsdl"/>
            </wsimport>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>
```